# Build failed with an exception: Invalid <color> for given resource value

Tags: android, flutter, material-ui, colors, build.gradle

When trying to run my Flutter App on an Pixel 5 Device I get the following error message:

```
/Users/username/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/0ace7b4637c402760ef38d3581a65ee0/transformed/appcompat-1.4.2/res/values/values.xml:37:4: Invalid <color> for given resource value.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.ResourceCompilerRunnable
   > Resource compilation failed. Check logs for details.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 22s
```

And here ist the some code of the file which produces the problem. Line 37 is the problem but I don't see why because it is correctly formatted like the line above.

```
...
35    <color name="foreground_material_light">@android:color/black</color>
36    <color name="highlighted_text_material_dark">#6680cbc4</color>
37    <color name="highlighted_text_material_light">#66009688</color>
38    <color name="material_blue_grey_800">#ff37474f</color>
...
```

Does someone have a possible solution for this error?

Answer (score -1):

The values appear to be in the correct format with color names and hex values assigned to them.

The error message you received suggests an issue with the color specified at line 37: `<color name="highlighted_text_material_light">#66009688</color>`. The color value format appears to be correct (an alpha value followed by RGB), so the error might not be immediately apparent from this snippet alone.

If the error persists despite the seemingly correct format, consider the following steps:

1. **Validate Syntax:** Ensure there are no typos, missing characters, or syntax errors in the file.
2. **Check Reference Consistency:** Ensure that any references, such as `@android:color/black`, are correctly defined and accessible.
3. **Other Occurrences:** Sometimes, errors reported at a specific line number might actually originate from earlier lines or other related files. Review the entire `values.xml` file for any potential related issues.
4. **Build Tools or IDE Cache:** If the error seems inexplicable, clearing the Gradle cache or rebuilding the project might help resolve some issues stemming from cached data.

Make sure to save any changes made to the `values.xml` file and then attempt to rebuild your project. If the issue persists, examining the complete error log or running a build with debugging options might provide more specific information to pinpoint the problem.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/10871073